# Using data from model in html file used in iFrame in my view

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, odata, sapui5

I have a pretty complex situation to solve

I had problems to display my canvas with an external library, so i gave up and i used an iframe in my view to display my chart. Now it's working well.

But now i have a question : How i can use my oData model in my html file, for my chart use the data from my sap table ? It has to be evolutive or it's useless

I show you how i did :

View :

```
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<mvc:View controllerName="Metrology.controllers.Pentagone" xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<html:iframe src="app/utils/testpentagone.html" height="1300" width="900"></html:iframe>
</mvc:View>
```

And this is the code of my pentagone :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >

    <title>SAPUI5</title>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<canvas id="radarChart" width="900" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
    <script>
var radarData = {
                labels : ["Performance","Security","Robustness","Changeability","Transferability"],
                datasets : [
                    {
                         fillColor: "rgba(102,45,145,.1)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(102,45,145,1)",
                        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                        data : [4,3,2,1.5,3]
                    },
                    {
                        fillColor: "rgba(63,169,245,.1)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(63,169,245,1)",
                        pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                        data : [3,3,3,3,3]
                    }
                ]
            }
            //Create Radar chart
            var pentagone = document.getElementById("radarChart").getContext("2d");
            var myNewChart = new Chart(pentagone).Radar(radarData);
</script>
```

Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do that is to add a timer into the game that pulls data from the back-end once in a while, and updates your chart.

In your situation I would just read the OData service using JQuery's getJSON call. This would be of much lighter weight compared to pulling the entire UI5 framework into your chart just to pull data from an OData service. The nice thing about OData services is that they behave quite RESTful(ish).

You could solve this using something like:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON("service/odata.svc/Entities('id123')", function(data) {
        myNewChart.datasets[0].points = data;
        myNewChart.update();
    });
}, 1000);
```

Please find a (mocked) version in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bojeka/1/edit?html,output). As I wasn't really sure where to find a public data provider with 5 changing values, I've mocked it up using a random generator. I hope the idea is clear though.

[image]

As promised, I have extended the example a bit so that Chart.js is embedded in a custom control. This custom control is embedded in a simple app that allows you to change the axis values, which should make the chart change accordingly. Have a look at the live app on https://jpenninkhof.github.io/pentagon/.

Sources are here: https://github.com/jpenninkhof/pentagon/. Please find the custom control in the controls directory.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering
I think that your answer is right, but shit i'm not able to do this alone. I'm a trainee in a big company, they ask me stuff i can't do alone, but nobody can help me.
I think i understood the "update" thing, but i'm not sure if you answered me about how to get my data
I just would like to be able to put in my data :
data : ["{products>Security}",{products>"Changeability}"...]
Like i do in my other views in sapui5

Comment: That sucks, sounds like they've really thrown you into the deep. Anyhow, for this particular app, is it your intention to have the user to key in 5 data points, are will you pull them from a server. I got the impression it was the latter, but don't mind enhancing the jsbin a bit with some input fields so that you get a clearer idea of how it could work.

Comment: Yeap, i was fine the 5 first weeks, but there i'm really lost
I think i will give up for this, i have 2 more days to find this, to make the doc.. so thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: As the famous John Cena said: "Never give up!". Sure you don't want to give it a try? Ping me directly on the UI5 slack (jpenninkhof).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my answer will suit your needs but anyway, it might be helpful.
From my perspective, if you want to use some custom UI elements from external libraries within UI5 app, it is better to wrap them up in custom UI5 control and then use them as usual. You can archieve this through **extend**.
In my specific example I was building control on top of D3js, and it looked like this:

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap/ui/thirdparty/d3");
jQuery.sap.declare("className");
sap.ui.core.Control.extend("className", {
init:...
renderer:...
onAfterRendering:...
...}
```

After, that I was able to instanciate this control in a usual manner and embed it into a page:

```
var chart = new classname();
return new sap.m.Page({
..
content: [chart],
});
```

My control was updated in a live mode, and I achieved this by watching end of animation and firing query to db and redrawing the control again (d3 supports this). 
But also agree that timer solution described above is pretty fine for this case.

Custom control creation [examples](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon20/helpdata/en/91/f184586f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm)

Comment: I already tried to put everything in my controller, but the canvas was empty, i don't really know why

Answer (score 0):

best way to fetch data in these kind of "live" scenarios is either use WebRTC (if your browser support) or use web sockets - above all when a lot of your dataset can be a lot smaller if you use binary mode during transfer.. use http-pooling with setInterval only when everything else fails (as a fail-safe method) - it's the worst possible performance you can ever achieve.